# How to create a custom arrow with two colors?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I would like to create a custom shape like this image

[image]

My HTML :

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class='row'>
    <div class="col-md-10 ">
        <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color: yellow;height: 38px;padding:0;">
            aaaaa
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1" style="padding:0;">
            <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color: green; border-radius: 0px 400px 50px 0px/0px 150px 23px 0px;">
                mmm
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color: red; border-radius: 0px 11px 400px 0px/0px 23px 150px 0px;">
                nnnn
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you not able to use SVG?

Comment: I want to get its data from backend and dynamically create it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use pseudo element and data attribute. You will be able de generate the HTML from backend without changing CSS (you simply need to adjust the color as you need) :

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.element {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.element:before {
  content: attr(data-before);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 50%;
  right: -42px;
  width: 40px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, black, red);
  border-top-right-radius: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  color: #fff;
  z-index:99;
}

.element:after {
  content: attr(data-after);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  right: -42px;
  width: 40px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, black, green);
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  color: #fff;
  z-index:99;
}
```

```html
<div class="element" data-before="A" data-after="B">
  content 1
</div>
<div class="element" data-before="C" data-after="D">
  content 2
</div>
<div class="element" data-before="E" data-after="F">
  content 3
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use HTML5 `canvas` tag and java script to draw you own image in 
you can read about it in below link 
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp